# Accessing network shares in Windows 8 when running application administrator

Tags: network-shares, windows-8-preview

I'm trying to access network shares from applications run as administrator, but the application can never find the network path, even if I use UNC format.  For example, I run notepad, hit *Open*, and type in `\\myserver\C$`.  It works.  I run notepad as an administrator and try the same, but I get `Windows cannot access \\myserver\C$`.  (I'm copying and pasting the path in case I made a typo, but my server isn't called myserver anyway.)

I can do this in Windows 7 without a problem.  How can I do this in Windows 8?

Comment: Does the error message only say that it cannot access the specified path or does it say anything else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm getting:

    Error code: 0x80070035
    The network path was not found.

Comment: Are your devices/PCs on DHCCP or have you assigned IP manually?

Comment: I have two computers, one with Windows 7 and one with Windows 8, both DHCP.  The server I don't know about. However, I can repeat the test on Windows 7 without a problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have been having a similar problem, and it looks as though this is the solution to both of our problems.

http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/

The link in the article to the Microsoft KB is for an article relating to Windows 7 / Vista, however other answers on the Microsoft site relating to Windows 8 are the same.
****In short**: UAC (User Account Control) is the problem in this situation as it tries to separate the user an administrator for greater security.